# Web App Vnet Integration using Azure CLI or API rest

Tags: azure, azure-cli, vnet

I've Tried to make the vnet integration of my web app using Azure CLI but only see the "z webapp vnet-integration" command. that is only for preview and does not work for me because the vnet integration preview only supports one service plan to one subnet.

I also see this option

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/createorupdatevnetconnection

but I'm confussing with the body parameters

are all of this parameters required? and where can I find it . thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, so simple.

I used the api rest and the body format only require the cert and vnetResourceId Parameters.

```
{
"properties":
    {
    "vnetResourceId": "/subscriptions/93f223ec-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/RG-OPENSHIFT-PROD/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnetname" ,
    "certBlob":"MIIDOD....."
    }
```

}

You can find the cert on the Point-to-site configuration page of the virtual network resource

Comment: You could accept the answer to close your question.